# Windows Mobile 6.5 Not Connect to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-mobile, sql-server-express

I have a software developed for the .NET Compact Framework 6.5 that runs on a Windows Mobile 6.5 device.

The software connects to a SQL Server Express database through the `System.Data.SqlClient` dll

The problem is that when I try to make the connection with `SqlConnection.Open`, I get a `SqlException` error.

The error is certainly related to the physical terminal because with another device virtually identical but that was already in my possession the program works without problems.

I think I miss some dll but I can not figure out which one. I have already installed the various sql wce5 armv4 CAB

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the exact exception message that you get?

Comment: the message contain only "SqlException on Sqlconnection.open"

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: I assume you have a network issue. The exception details will be very helpful. If a DLL could not be found, the code would show different error already during load. Possibly you specify a name and not an IP and the network does not resolve the name...But without further details??

Comment: This is the Error Message: 
sqlexception
at
System.Data.Sqlclient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TsdParserState state)
at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,TsdParserState state)
at
System.Data.SqlClient.TsdParserState.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at
System.Data.SqlClient.TsdParser.Connect(Sring host, SqlInternalConnection connHandler,Int32 timeout)
at
System.Data.Sqlclient.SqlInternalConnection.OpenAndLogin()
at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection..ctor(SqlConnection connection,HashTable connectionOptions)